# Count Total Transaction each specific row even if 0

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a 3 Columns namely:

1. `Payment Channel`
2. `Payment Name`
3. `Total Transaction`

The `Total Transaction` will be the **COUNT** of each `Payment Channel` and `Payment Name`.

In the `Payment Channel`, values have `PC01`-`PC09`.

I want my result to display all the `Payment Channel` even if no transactions.

**Here is my SQL Script:**

```
SELECT
    B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL AS Payment_Channel,
    COMM_CODE.CODE_NAME AS Payment_Name,
    COUNT(B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID) AS Total_Transaction
FROM B2C_BUY_LOG
INNER JOIN B2C_BUY_HIST ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID = B2C_BUY_HIST.PAY_ID
INNER JOIN COMM_CODE ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL = COMM_CODE.CODE
WHERE B2C_BUY_LOG.RET_CODE = 1
AND B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID LIKE '190220%'
AND COMM_CODE.CODE IN('PC01', 'PC02', 'PC03', 'PC04', 'PC05', 'PC06', 'PC07', 'PC08', 'PC09')
GROUP BY Payment_Channel, Payment_Name;
```

**Here is the result of my Query:**

```
Payment_Channel   Payment_Name    Total_Transaction
PC01              Name-1          14
PC02              Name-2          2
PC03              Name-3          7
PC04              Name-4          9
PC06              Name-6          21
PC08              Name-8          18
PC09              Name-9          95
```

This query returns only the match values between the joined tables because it is **INNER JOIN** and the **PC05** and **PC07** is missing on the result because it has no transaction. I also tried different **JOINS**.

How can I display the `PC05` and `PC07` with a count of **0** if no transaction?

Thanks!

Comment: Which table stores "transactions"?

Comment: Why are you joining the `B2C_BUY_HIST` - It's not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, Issue is with column on which filter is applied.

```
SELECT
    B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL AS Payment_Channel,
    COMM_CODE.CODE_NAME AS Payment_Name,
    COUNT(B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID) AS Total_Transaction
FROM B2C_BUY_LOG
left outer JOIN B2C_BUY_HIST ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID = B2C_BUY_HIST.PAY_ID
left outer INNER JOIN COMM_CODE ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL = COMM_CODE.CODE
WHERE B2C_BUY_LOG.RET_CODE = 1
AND B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID LIKE '190220%'
AND B2C_BUY_LOG.CODE IN('PC01', 'PC02', 'PC03', 'PC04', 'PC05', 'PC06', 'PC07', 'PC08', 'PC09')
GROUP BY Payment_Channel, Payment_Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join and move your other condition in ON Clause like below-

```
SELECT
    B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL AS Payment_Channel,
    COMM_CODE.CODE_NAME AS Payment_Name,
    COUNT(B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID) AS Total_Transaction
FROM B2C_BUY_LOG
left JOIN B2C_BUY_HIST ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID = B2C_BUY_HIST.PAY_ID and B2C_BUY_LOG.RET_CODE = 1 AND B2C_BUY_LOG.PAY_ID LIKE '190220%'
left JOIN COMM_CODE ON B2C_BUY_LOG.PG_CHANNEL = COMM_CODE.CODE
and COMM_CODE.CODE IN('PC01', 'PC02', 'PC03', 'PC04', 'PC05', 'PC06', 'PC07', 'PC08', 'PC09')
GROUP BY Payment_Channel, Payment_Name;
```

Comment: `Payment_Name` is an alias for `COMM_CODE.CODE_NAME`. Grouping by a left joined table column (usually) makes no sense.